# Firebase messaging android notification has no sound or priority

Tags: java, android, cordova, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use the following code to send a firebase notification to my android device which runs cordova.

```
public Message buildMessage(NotificationDTO notificationDTO) {
    return Message.builder()
            .setAndroidConfig(buildAndroidConfig(notificationDTO))
            .setApnsConfig(buildApnsConfig(notificationDTO))
            .setToken(notificationDTO.getToken())
            .build();
}

public AndroidConfig buildAndroidConfig(NotificationDTO notificationDTO) {
    AndroidNotification androidNotification = AndroidNotification.builder()
            .setPriority(AndroidNotification.Priority.MAX)
            .setVisibility(AndroidNotification.Visibility.PUBLIC)
            .setTitle(notificationDTO.getTitle())
            .setBody(notificationDTO.getBody())
            .setSound("default")
            .build();

    return AndroidConfig.builder()
            .setNotification(androidNotification)
            .build();
}
```

The device does not show notifications on lock screen & will not make a sound or vibrate even though priority has been set to MAX and visibility to PUBLIC

Peculiar thing is if the phone (Xiaomi mi10) is set to silent, the notification will vibrate. The two problems are probably linked together but I could use some assistance.